# WordPress WP_Query - Como mostrar apenas post pai?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Boa noite a todos, tenho um CPT onde cada post tem seu filho, ao listar isso com o WP_Query, na página é mostrado todos os posts (pai e filho), porém eu quero mostrar só os posts 'pai', como posso fazer isso?

Desde já muito obrigado!

segue o código usado:

```
 <!-- primeiro Loop -->
      <?php
       $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'novellist'                
       );
       $novels = new WP_Query( $args );

       if( $novels->have_posts() ):
          while( $novels->have_posts() ): $novels->the_post();
       ?>
       <!-- Post -->
       <div class="col-12 post1">
           <?php get_template_part('template_parts/content', 'archive-novel'); ?>
       </div>
       <!-- End Post -->
       <?php
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
       ?>
```

Comment: No título você diz *post pai*, no corpo da pergunta você diz * categoria pai e filha*. Quem tem filhos é o *CPT* ou a *categoria*? **São coisas bem diferentes**.

Comment: Peço desculpas pelo o erro, tenho um CPT chamado ''Novels List" e tenho uma taxomania chamada ''novels'' atrelado ao CPT. No CPT tenho o post pai (que recebe a categoria pai) e o post filho( que recebe a categoria filho). Editei o post inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, você pode usar o parâmetro `post_parent`. Quando um post tem "0" como parent, significa que não tem pai, logo, não é post filho.

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'novellist',
   'post_parent' => 0    
 );
```

([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414669/wordpress-wp-query-query-parent-pages-only))

Comment: acho que fiz algo errado, todos os post sumiram quando uso esse argumento

Comment: @GustavoSiqueira editei a resposta depois que você esclareceu a ambiguidade.

Comment: Peço desculpa pelo meu erro, acabei confundindo as taxomanias com os posts, muito obrigado pela ajuda!